# didSelectItem not called on UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, iglistkit

**UPDATE**

If I tap and drag on my UICollectionViewCell, then release, didSelectItem gets called. But if I just tap, it doesn't recognise the tap! Why is that?

I have a UIViewController with three container views (embedded via the Storyboard). When I press a button, one of these views appears. Each container view is managed by a `UIViewController` that contains a `UICollectionView`. I control this `UICollectionView` using [IGListKit](https://github.com/Instagram/IGListKit). Each cell is managed by something called a section controller - a piece of code that handles the delegate and datasource methods for each cell in the section, e.g. `cellForItem`, `didSelectItem`... However, when I select a cell, `didSelectItem` is never called. I've checked the obvious things like making sure data sources are connected and making sure the collection view/cell has userInteraction enabled. What's strange is this same setup works in another part of my app (using the same section controller), except the collection view there isn't embedded in a container view. Anyone have any idea what might be happening?

Some code:

Assigning my container view to a variable:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ViewersOfLivestreamViewController" {
        if let viewController = segue.destination as? LivestreamInvitationParentViewController {
            viewersOfLivestreamViewController = viewController
            viewersOfLivestreamViewController.delegate = self
        }
    }
}
```

Initialising an adapter inside my container view to handle the `UICollectionView`:

```
adapter = ListAdapter(updater: ListAdapterUpdater(), viewController: self, workingRangeSize: 10)
adapter.collectionView = collectionView
adapter.dataSource = self
adapter.scrollViewDelegate = self
```

Setting the section controller that the cells use:

```
func listAdapter(_ listAdapter: ListAdapter, sectionControllerFor object: Any) -> ListSectionController {
    let sectionController = FriendsSectionController()
    sectionController.sectionModel = model
    sectionController.delegate = self
    return sectionController
}
```

Inside my section controller, this function should get called, but never does:

```
override func didSelectItem(at index: Int) {
    // This never gets called
}
```

Comment: did you set the delegate for your collectionView?

Comment: Can you present some code?

Comment: @ReinierMelian No because `IGListKit` uses an `adaptor` that handles the delegate and datasource for you.

Comment: @Miket25 I added some...

Comment: @Tometoyou your `FriendsSectionController` is a subclass of `IGListSectionController`? or `IGListSingleSectionController`?

Comment: @ReinierMelian yeah, well ListSectionController. Also I've just been tapping randomly lots of times in different places on my cell and it just happened to call didSelectItem once... But i've no idea how that worked...

Comment: try implementing `func didSelect(_ sectionController: ListSingleSectionController, with object: Any)` and let me know

Comment: have you added any other gesture recognisers to the view hierarchy?

Comment: @Scriptable Yes! I've just solved it by turning off "cancelsTouchesInView" on one of the recognisers. However, that view is nothing to do with the collection view, its in the main UIViewController. But that seemed to work!!

Comment: it must have something to do with it otherwise it wouldn't interfere. I've seen this issue a number of times, thats why I asked about the recogniser straight away. check your view hierarchy and you should find the solution